# What's the difference between the Google Calendar API scopes - calendar.readonly and calendar.events.readonly?

Tags: google-calendar-api

According to the documentation ([here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth)), Google provides somewhat identical scopes:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar          read/write access
  to Calendars
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly    read-only access
  to Calendars
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events read/write access to
  Events
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly    read-only
  access to Events

What is the difference calendar.readonly and calendar.events.readonly?
And what's the difference between the non readonly ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### If you consult the [Google Calendar API references](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference) you can see the scopes necessary for the individual requests

So, you can see e.g. that for the methods like [Calendars: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) or [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) you need one of the following scopes:

[image]

while for [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) or `Events: get` the possible scopes are:

[image]

In other words:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly

is more restrictive than

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly

**The former allows you only to retrieve event specific information, not general calendar related information.**

Then,

- if you want to insert, patch or update an event, you need at least the scope

  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events

  (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar also possible)
- while for inserting, patching or updating a calendar you need the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar